# Where GEM collects gem paths from?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am new to ruby/rails and I have a rails project on my (Ubuntu guest OS) virtual machine.

Until recently, I used `Putty` terminal program to access the directories (Via SSH). Everything used to work fine.

But now I set up VScode [remote ssh connection](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) in order to have better access and view of the project files.

The problem is when I connect via vscode-ssh the gem environment is different. More specifically the gem paths are different

**VScode ssh-terminal**:

```
$ pwd
/home/usermuser/git/frontend
$ rvm current
ruby-2.3.7
ruby -v
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [x86_64-linux]
$ gem env
.....
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.2.3
.....
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/usermuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648
     - /home/usermuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@global
.....
.....
```

**Putty** terminal:

```
$ pwd
/home/usermuser/git/frontend
$ rvm current
ruby-2.3.7
ruby -v
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [x86_64-linux]
$ gem env
.....
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.6
.....
 - GEM PATHS:
    - /home/usermuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7
    - /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0

.....
.....
```

Please note the `RUBYGEMS VERSION` is different and the paths are different accordingly.
Why the GEM is different, where this configuration come from? Where GEM gets paths from?

Answer (score 0):

This is `rvm` who sets and reads `GEM_PATH` in your case.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/0233c51c9d8ca9e229833dac5f232b500d3e86e5/scripts/gemsets#L411) of this *OSS* project.

It’s being set in scripts, that `rvm` puts into your shell `rc` scripts. Depending on your shell, it’s probably `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`, or like.

It seems like `VScode ssh-terminal` does not execute this, which probably means it’s not configured to start as a normal login shell.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right. Vscode `echo $0` >>  `/bin/bash`, whilst putty `echo $0` >> `-bash`. So definetly the shell is different, but how to make vscode shell as putty? The vscode ssh uses configuration file of this type: https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config